# Why my application doesn't start after the installation in samsung knox?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, failed-installation, mobile-devices, samsung-knox

I installed my custom application within a knox workspace, through an MDM.
The installation ends without errors, but when i try to open the application i get the error

> "Unfortunately, APP has stopped"

Not even the splashscreen appears.

What really confuses me is that the same application(apk) works perfectly if installed manually in the very same device but outside the knox workspace.

Going through the log i found this error:

> android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.something.myapplication

seems like something went wrong during the installation.

Is there a particular requirement to run my application within knox, or is there something else?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question hoping this could help someone else.
The issue was that the apk wasn't correctly signed.

Once correctly re-build with the appropriate signature, everything worked fine.